# I have a multiple classes in python i.e class a, class b, class c, class d then how can i accassed the specific class method

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I have a multiple classes in python i.e class a, class b, class c, class d and  class d in inheriting the class a,class b, class c and class a, class b, class c having a method m1() then I want to access  only the  method of class b then how can I access this method?? plz reffer following code.

```
class a:
       def m1(self):
              print("Class A method m1")

class b:
       def m1(self):
              print("Class B method m1")

class c:
       def m1(self):
              print("Class C method m1")

class d(a,b,c):
       def m2(self):
              print("Class D method m1")
       b().m1()

o1 = d()
o1.m1()
```

Comment: Can we assume that the call to `m1` is supposed to be inside the definition of `d.m2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options, all of which may have wider consequences for the rest of your code. You cannot necessarily pick one of the following in a vacuum; you have to consider how your hierarchy as a whole is supposed to work.

1. Change the inheritance order.

   ```
   class d(b, a ,c):  # Put b first
       def m2(self):
           super().m1()  # b.m1 is the first one found
   ```
2. Alter the starting point of the search for `b.m1`

   ```
   class d(a, b, c):
       def m2(self):
           # self.__mro__() returns [d, a, b, c]
           super(a, self).m1()  # Start looking after a instead of d
   ```
3. Refer directly to the method you want instead of going through the MRO

   ```
   class d(a, b, c):
       def m2(self):
           b.m1(self)
   ```

Comment: Option 3. seems like the cleanest idea.

Comment: (Removed my previous comment, because I'm not sure option 3 is worse than option 2 with regards to the need for a redesign.)

Comment: I like option 1, because it's explicitly about a `d` instance being more like a `b` instance than an `a` or `c` instance. But if that similarity only relates to the definition of `m1`, then there's definitely a problem with the design of the hierarchy.